# Using admob rewarded ad in unity singleton pattern

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

I am using admob ads in my app and they are working fine. But when i try to do something after a ad close or reward earned call back my code breaks. Following is my adMob script

```
public class AdMobScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    ...

    public event Action OnReviveRewardEarned;
    public event Action OnReviveAdLoaded;
    public event Action OnReviveAdClosed;

    private void LoadReviveRewardedAd()
    {

        reviveRewardedAd = new RewardedAd(adReviveRewardedId);

        reviveRewardedAd.OnAdLoaded += ReviveAdLoaded;
        reviveRewardedAd.OnUserEarnedReward += ReviveEarnedReward;
        reviveRewardedAd.OnAdClosed += ReviveAdClosed;

        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        reviveRewardedAd.LoadAd(request);

    }

    private void ReviveAdClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadReviveRewardedAd();
        if (isRewardErned)
        {
            isRewardErned = false;
            OnReviveRewardEarned.Invoke();
        }
        else
            OnReviveAdClosed.Invoke();
    }

    private void ReviveEarnedReward(object sender, Reward e)
    {
        isRewardErned = true;
    }

    private void ReviveAdLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //reviveButton.interactable = true;
        OnReviveAdLoaded.Invoke();
    }

    public void ShowAdToRevive()
    {
        if (reviveRewardedAd.IsLoaded())
        {
            reviveRewardedAd.Show();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

In the callbacks i am calling my adManager script which is in term using adMob script. Here is the code for it.

```
public class AdManager : MonoBehaviour
{
   ...
   private void Start() {

        AdMobScript.instance.OnReviveAdClosed += ReviveAdClosed;
        AdMobScript.instance.OnReviveAdLoaded += ReviveAdLoaded;
        AdMobScript.instance.OnReviveRewardEarned += ReviveReward;

    }

    #region ReviveAds
    private void ReviveReward() {
        //game crash here
        backButton.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        reviveButton.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        noThanksButton.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        manager.Revive();
    }
    private void ReviveAdLoaded() {
        reviveButton.interactable = true;
    }
    private void ReviveAdClosed() {
        //game crash here
        reviveButton.interactable = false;
    }

    public void ShowAdToRevive() {
        AdMobScript.instance.ShowAdToRevive();
    }
   ...
}
```

After either ad close or reward earned my game crashes (error log says

`get_gameObject can only be called from the main thread`

). There must be something i am doing wrong. Can anyone please point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the problem - you trying to manipulate with MonoBehaviors, not in main thread.

Just write simple scheduler which calls the events in the Unity thread, like this:

Scheduler:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class Scheduler : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static Scheduler instance;

    public event Action secondTick = delegate { };

    private float seconds = 0;

    private void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        seconds += Time.unscaledDeltaTime;

        if (seconds >= 1.0f)
        {
            seconds -= 1.0f;

            secondTick.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

Updated AdMobScript:

```
public class AdMobScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    ...

    private bool onRewardEarnedCall = false;
    private bool onRewardAdLoaded = false;
    private bool onRewardAdClosed = false;
    
    public event Action OnReviveRewardEarned;
    public event Action OnReviveAdLoaded;
    public event Action OnReviveAdClosed;

    private void LoadReviveRewardedAd()
    {

        reviveRewardedAd = new RewardedAd(adReviveRewardedId);

        reviveRewardedAd.OnAdLoaded += ReviveAdLoaded;
        reviveRewardedAd.OnUserEarnedReward += ReviveEarnedReward;
        reviveRewardedAd.OnAdClosed += ReviveAdClosed;

        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        reviveRewardedAd.LoadAd(request);


        Scheduler.instance.secondTick += OnSecondTick;
    }

    private void OnSecondTick()
    {
        if(onRewardAdClosed)
        {
            onRewardAdClosed = false;

            OnReviveAdClosed.Invoke();
        }
        
        if(onRewardEarnedCall)
        {
            OnReviveRewardEarned.Invoke();
            onRewardEarnedCall = false;
        }
        
        if(onRewardAdLoaded)
        {
            OnReviveAdLoaded.Invoke();
            onRewardAdLoaded = false;
        }
    }
    
    private void ReviveAdClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadReviveRewardedAd();
        if (isRewardErned)
        {
            isRewardErned = false;
            onRewardEarnedCall = true;
        }
        else
            onRewardAdClosed = true;
    }

    private void ReviveEarnedReward(object sender, Reward e)
    {
        isRewardErned = true;
    }

    private void ReviveAdLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //reviveButton.interactable = true;
        onRewardAdLoaded = true;
    }

    public void ShowAdToRevive()
    {
        if (reviveRewardedAd.IsLoaded())
        {
            reviveRewardedAd.Show();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

This is a very simple and not optimize solution but this will solve your problem.

Comment: That's brilliant! But what about if i want to register one more scheduler? I am not sure if something like this would work.
`Scheduler.instance.secondTick += OnSecondTick;`
`Scheduler.instance.secondTick += OnSnakeSecondTick;`
Is it a good idea to make another static property in the scheduler? like:
`public event Action anotherSecondTick = delegate { };`

Comment: Not necessary, you can use this event for another tick handlers. If this answer helped you mark it.

Comment: Just finished implementing your solution. I got the NullReferanceException for 'instance' on `Scheduler.instance.secondTick += OnSecondTick;`

Comment: It's possible exception, you need to initialize Scheduler earlier than you call this - Scheduler.instance.secondTick += OnSecondTick;

Comment: maybe take this line in the `Start` function?

Comment: No, how is this method called? 'LoadReviveRewardedAd'

Comment: Either here in 'ReviveAdClosed' or here 'ShowAdToRevive'

Comment: Is you attach Scheduler script on any object at scene? And in AdMobScript call this line - Scheduler.instance.secondTick += OnSecondTick; in Start method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217708/discussion-between-mubeen-khalid-and-onionfan).